# Excel script run from Power Automate. Formula doesn't update

Tags: excel, excel-formula, auto-update, power-automate, office-scripts

Power Automate runs the script every day (08:00).
In this script I compare the current date with another date (column C). This check is done by the formula. The result is placed in column D. The final check is to put information into the array only if the number (Column D) is <=24.

The problem is that when **Power Automate runs the script the formula doesn't update column D**.
If I open the workbook the formula is updated and the script works.

**Example Sheet:**

[image]

In **column D** there is this formula (cell D2) `=D2-$E$2` and so on.
In the **column E2** there is the current date with formula `=today()`

**Example code:**

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

  //first step. update formula
   workbook.getApplication().calculate(ExcelScript.CalculationType.full);

  // Get the "MyWorksheet" worksheet from the workbook.
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("MyWorksheet");
  let range = selectedSheet.getUsedRange();
  let rangeValues = range.getValues();

  const arr= [];

  for(let i=0; i< rangeValues.length; i++){
      
      //compare the number (column D)
      if(rangeValues[i][3]<=24){
        arr.push(rangeValues[i][0]);
      }
  }  
}
```

Where am I wrong?

I tried with manual and automatic calculation mode but without result.

To temporarily solve the problem, decrease the value in column D by 1 every day without using the formula.

Comment: Are the dates in column C Excel serial dates or a general format?

Comment: Sorry but just confirm my understanding, is your issue that because the workbook hasn't been opened, the formula still shows the date on the day that the workbook last calculated, correct?

Comment: @Jeffrey, the script works if I open the workbook and use Power automate. While, if I don't open the workbook the next day the formula doesn't update. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, @Skin. If I don't open the workbook the formula doesn't update. Thanks for your help. Power automate is so fast or  am I wrong in the code?

Comment: Do you know if `E2` is getting updated to reflect the correct date when running with Power Automate while the workbook is closed? Or only the column D is having the problem? For troubleshooting, you can try to add some `console.log(...)` in your code to check the content of range `E2`, `D2`, `D3`, etc. You can find the console log outputs in Power Automate by looking into the Run script action (the `body` box) in the run history of your flow.

Comment: Ok, @YutaoHuang, I'll try to write with console.log the current date from E2 and a value from column D. Thanks for your help. however, I think the formulas do not update due to a "synchronism" problem.

Comment: I had a few thoughts here. 1) In the loop, could you be trying to evaluate or compare two different types, a string and a number and thus returning nothing? That doesn't seem to be the case because the script works while within Excel. 2) In my investigation I found that the getTexts() seems to return the calculated cell. I'm not sure why this is the case. Doing so you might need to convert the result to a number to do the comparison. 3) Dates can be tricky. I've run into cases where the zero hour gets interpreted as current date - 1. This likely isn't happening but thought I might mention.

Comment: I couldn’t reproduce your issue. I tried with a worksheet calculate and a workbook calculate prior to copying the value of the formula over they both worked so yeah, interesting one.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.  I will also try to insert the current data with JavaScript and paste it into cell E2.I will update you as soon as the tests are done.  I really appreciate your help.